# MySQL row group query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, report

I have got a table like

```
id    |    name    |    registered_date    |  
------+------------+-----------------------+--
4     |  Name 1    |  2015-02-15 00:00:00  |
5     |  Name 1    |  2014-02-15 00:00:00  |
6     |  Name 1    |  2015-02-15 00:00:00  |
7     |  Name 1    |  2013-02-15 00:00:00  |
8     |  Name 1    |  2015-02-15 00:00:00  |
9     |  Name 1    |  2015-02-15 00:00:00  |
10    |  Name 1    |  2015-02-15 00:00:00  |
11    |  Name 1    |  2015-02-15 00:00:00  |
12    |  Name 1    |  2015-02-15 00:00:00  |
13    |  Name 1    |  2015-02-15 00:00:00  |
14    |  Name 1    |  2015-02-15 00:00:00  |
```

in 'registered_date" field keeping the date of user registered

Now I need to take the count of users in each month registered.

Is it possible using the current structure ? Result will be something like this

```
totalCOunt    |     momthYear
--------------+----------------
144           |     Feb-2015
--------------+----------------
100           |     Mar-2015
--------------+----------------
104           |     Apr-2015
--------------+----------------
174           |     May-2015
--------------+----------------
144           |     June-2015
--------------+----------------
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount, DATE_FORMAT(registered_date, '%M-%Y') AS momthYear
FROM tablename
GROUP BY by momthYear
ORDER BY momthYear`